# shell script to sleep at an increment of 10

Tags: shell, shell-script

shell script to sleep at an increment of 10 lines. I want my script to sleep for 3 mins after every 10 lines its read. then pick up from the last line. I'm not good with script, so I dunno where start, If anyone has an idea please give me some suggestions. Thanks for helping and reading

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please add more information.

Comment: basically, i want to write a script to read out of  a file then do some commands; after every 10 lines. sleep, then pick up from the last line.

Comment: 10 lines of what? Input? Output? Script? Please can you provide an example.

Comment: hey Roaima, I have a file with hundreds of hostname, I want to write a script to read from that file, and at every 10th line. sleep for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read var
do
    echo $var #here you can do more stuff with $var (this is your line)

    count=$(( $count+1 ))
    if [ "$count" = "10" ]; then
        count=0
        sleep 180
    fi
done
```

You can then save this as, for instance, `foo.sh`, set it to be executable with `chmod +x foo.sh`, and run it like:

```
cat your_file.txt | ./foo.sh
```

What this script does is to read one line of input, save it into `var`, print it, increase the counter to 1, and when it reaches 10 iterations (i.e. 10 lines read) it sleeps and reset the counter. Then loop like this till there is no more input.

Comment: I'm glad this was useful (=